# Phone number to a lounge, or lounges generally

Tags: airlines, lounges

I am trying to find the direct phone number to United Club, Terminal E, at IAH Houston airport.

It doesn't seem to be online - only the general UA 800 number.

Does anyone know it, or more usefully, where to find it.  (Or, ultimately, where to find those numbers for all brands of lounges.)

(Calling the general United 800 number and asking is not practiable: it's a 20 minute wait these days.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Yellowpages.com says](https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/mip/united-club-520880435?lid=520880435) the number is +1 (281) 553-0400, and suggests an alternate number +1 (281) 230-3100.

Yellowpages.com is the web based descendant of the physical printed telephone directories that were (and still are in some areas) distributed to everyone with a landline telephone in the USA. It is so named because business telephone listings are printed on yellow paper.

I called both numbers. There was no answer on the first number, so I can't be sure it is actually for the lounge. The second number turned out to be for the airport itself. The automated system did give me an option for airport paging, so if you are trying to reach someone who is in the airport, that might be an option.

Comment: I'd just add that for the generic answer for any airport, calling the airport and getting connected to the airport operator is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Zach If the airport has such a thing.

Comment: As a curiosity: I actually did call United's general 800 number and waited the 20 minutes, and then asked them the number.  553 0400 is indeed the number for "E" lounge, but as Michael mentions it never answers.  In fact, the number for the other united lounge at IAH (gate C I think) is 553 1815.  They always answer!  So I called them.  Hope it helps someone  :)